# Possible to screw machine screw in wall?

Tags: walls, screws, drill

**Background**

I would like to build picture frames, where there on the back is a hole with 18mm in diameter and 7mm in depth. In the hole will I glue a 2mm metal plate.

On the wall would I like to screw in a magnet, like the one below, which is 16mm in diameter and 5mm in depth.

The picture frame will rest on the top of the magnet, and the magnetism will prevent the frame from tipping.

**Question**

Is it possible to screw an M4 machine screw like the one below into a brick wall?

If so, what is required?

[image]

Comment: It might help if we knew why you wanted to screw them into a wall.

Comment: Good idea. Have been provided now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind. 
First You could check your local hardware store for a concrete type anchor that has an internal threaded, You may get lucky and find it has the thread size you need.

Secondly you could drill a hole ~ twice the diameter (or so) of the thread with a masonry drill bit into the brick. Fill the hole with epoxy and place the magnet thread in the hole. A piece of "Duct" tape could hold the magnet in place until the epoxy cures. If you ever need to remove the magnet, it should be able to unscrew from the epoxy "nut".

Comment: In a similar venue, you can embed a long nut in the epoxy (or other glue), thus really giving you the flexibility of unscrewing. Use a longer nut so that the glue won't ruin the threads where the bolt will sit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Command adhesive strips to hang the frame?  They have some designed for this exact purpose.